# Create new DocuSign account

Tags: docusignapi

I am not able to create new account via web service AccountManagment. I used [NewAccount](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Account%20Management%20Service%20API/NewAccount.htm%3FTocPath%3DAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7CAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Methods%7C_____24) for create it.

1. After import [AccountManagment](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Account%20Management%20Service%20API/Account%20Management%20Service%20API%20Methods.htm%3FTocPath%3DAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7CAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Methods%7C_____0) as web service in Visual Studio 2013 it service does not have type AccountSettings. Without it is not possible make call to API.
2. This is method very big. Is possible omit some fields? Adobe EchoSign API call for create user more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a new user (and you're using SOAP not REST) then there's a different call you need to make.  See the **AddMembersToAccount()** SOAP call which is also part of the AccountManagementService:

https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/accountmanagement.asmx?op=AddMembersToAccount

Comment: It should not new member for existing account. It should new account.